# Comparing two character values in a Coldfusion cfquery

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a database field which contains `VARCHAR` values like

```
XY23(CX Web)
```

AND I am writing a Query of Queries like

```
SELECT qPdfs.filename, qPdfs.code, qObjects.id
FROM qPdfs, qObjects
WHERE qPdfs.code = qObjects.code
```

OR like

```
SELECT qPdfs.filename, qPdfs.code, qObjects.id
FROM qPdfs, qObjects
WHERE <cfqueryparam value="#qObjects.code#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR"> = <cfqueryparam value="#qPdfs.code#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">
```

But I am getting an error message like

```
XY23(CX Web) must be interpretable as a valid number in the current locale.
```

Any help?

Thank you

Comment: So you are saying that the 2 different tables each have a column named "code" that is a CARCHAR type? What's CARACHAR? Do you mean VARCHAR maybe?  Also - have you tried joining the 2 queries (actually using the JOIN syntax)?

Comment: Yes it was actually VARCHAR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are both of the database columns type `varchar`? If so, the QoQ is probably applying some implicit conversion based on the contents of the columns. If some of the codes are all numeric, the QoQ may be attempting to cast them to numbers internally before performing the comparison. Hence the error.  `cfqueryparam` won't help here, because it can only be used on literals, not query columns. If a straight equality comparison ie `ColName = ColName` causes that error, try casting instead:

```
WHERE CAST(qPdfs.code AS VARCHAR) = CAST(qObjects.code AS VARCHAR)
```

NB: QoQ string comparisons are case sensitive, so you may want to convert the columns to upper/lower case first.